# Vue.js "The "el" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Here is the html code. I am trying to call this id using vue.js but couldn't get that and it shows warning.

```
                   <div id="SignesConcept">
                      <!-- Signes -->
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="box box-success">
                            <div class="box-header">
                              <h3 class="font-alt text-left">Signes</h3>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Vue.js code:

```
var SignesConcept = Vue.extend({
    el: '#SignesConcept',
    data: function(){
        return {
            show:true
        }
    },
})

router.map({
    '/SignesConcept':{
        component: SignesConcept
    } 
});
```

When i call template id there is no problem but when i am trying to call div id inside template it's not working. If anyone have any idea about it. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you defining the `el` for a component (which could in theory exist multiple times)? Use `<router-view>` instead.

Comment: I am using router view. But to call id i used el:'Div Id'. router map will call it in router view

Comment: Why do you need to call an id? I'm really not sure what you're trying to do with the id.

Comment: Here is the thing I have many different templates and inside a template i have links to access div's. So when i click on that link i could directly access that div.

Comment: And why do you need to set `el` for that?

Comment: "el" i used for element id because i can't access using "template"

Comment: here is the link http://ocelles.inshea.fr/onepage/#!/concept    on this page when i click on signes/definition/remarques it should go to Signes/definitions/remarques like it works in one page app

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm getting more and more confused by what you're trying to do. Either way, it doesn't seem that you need to use `el` in this case, unless I'm really misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: i am using this https://vuejs.org/guide/migration-vue-router.html#ad

Answer (score 0):

Define your templates inside template tags

```
<template id="SignesConcept"> 
  // Define your template here.
</template>
```

Then use **template** attribute instead of **el** to reference this template from your our component options.

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

var SignesConcept = Vue.extend({
  template: '#SignesConcept',
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
})

var App = {}

var router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
  '/SignesConcept': {
    component: SignesConcept
  }
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/0.7.13/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <a v-link="{ path: '/SignesConcept' }">Go to Signes</a>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<template id="SignesConcept">
  <!-- Signes -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="font-alt text-left">Signes</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```